# Angular JS Date filter not working (Datetime)

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I'm trying to filter a field from database that is Datetime type.

I'm doing this:

```
<b style='display: block'>{{o.dataCadastro| date:'medium'}}
```

The expected is: **"00:33:10 15-02-2018"**,  But is returning **"2018-02-15 00:33:10"**

For "Date" field from database is working fine.

Comment: I am using "América/Sao_Paulo". 
Like a said, with type "Date" from database is working fine.

Comment: Have you [set a locale file](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) for Angular to use? If so, [which one](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale)?

Comment: So have you included [`angular-locale_pt-br.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_pt-br.js)?

Comment: Yes, this file: [angular-locale_pt-br.js](http://alternativesistemas.com.br/site/angular-locale_pt-br.js)

Comment: Looks like your localisation file is out-of-date. See how it has `"medium": "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`? Still doesn't explain why your date is formatted the way it is unless you're not actually including that file

Answer (score 0):

[Your localisation file](http://alternativesistemas.com.br/site/angular-locale_pt-br.js) sets *"medium"* to

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

If you were to include the up-to-date [`angular-locale_pt-br.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_pt-br.js), the "medium" date format is

```
"d 'de' MMM 'de' y HH:mm:ss"
```

Using that, your date would appear as *"15 de fev de 2018 00:33:10"*.

You can update or edit your localisation file or, if you're after a specific format, just pass it in to the filter, eg

```
{{o.dataCadastro| date:'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-YYYY'}}
```